# How to include AdSense in an Android Titanium Application?

Tags: android, admob, titanium-mobile, adsense, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Titanium SDK 2.1.3 and developing for Android 2.3 and greater.

So far I haven't found a proper way to implement AdSense. I read I should load an HTML in a WebView, but [it seems that causes to Google to disable your AdSense account](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117141/google-adsense-and-android).

[The only module I found so far](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/admob/mobile/android/documentation/index.md), used AdMob, but it doesn't work with my project, failing to create a R.java when compiling.

How can I integrate AdSense into my Android application? What guidelines should I follow to add this to my application in Titanium so Goodle doesn't disable my account?

I will appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: If the Titanium app compiles into a native Android application, then Google's policy is you should use AdMob and not AdSense. I'm not familiar with the Titanium platform though so I can't tell you why the plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AdMob, not AdSense, for mobile applications. The module you linked to is correct, and in working order (I'm using it currently in production apps with only minor modifications).

In android, after you have included the module in tiapp.xml, you also have to add this to your tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
        <tool-api-level>16</tool-api-level>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

These settings worked great for me, also make sure you actually have that SDK and tool level, if not open up the Android SDK manager and download them.

Comment: I tried this with `minSdkVersion="8"` and worked like a charm too. It seems that as long as the `targetSdkVersion`and the `tool-api-level`are equal or greater than 12, the ads with AdMob will be displayed in Android 2.3 and lower.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked and that is good to know for the future.

Comment: yeah, it seems that as long as you specify a target that  meets the requirements for the module, any device that meets the minimum version will run it.